# Pipenv not working after upgrade to python (Homebrew installed)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, homebrew

It appears pipenv and other python packages on my Mac are tied to Python 3.6 but should work fine with 3.7. I recently updated to python via

`brew upgrade python`

Running 3.7.0

$ pipenv update
Warning: Python 3.6 was not found on your system…
You can specify specific versions of Python with:
  $ pipenv --python path/to/python

When I try to specify the path... I get:

```
$ pipenv --python 3.7 update
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: /Users/zane/src/dinghy-ping/Pipfile
Using /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 (3.7.0) to create virtualenv…
⠸Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py:1041: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
New python executable in /Users/zane/.local/share/virtualenvs/dinghy-ping-ePAjWOtt/bin/python3.7
Not overwriting existing python script /Users/zane/.local/share/virtualenvs/dinghy-ping-ePAjWOtt/bin/python (you must use /Users/zane/.local/share/virtualenvs/dinghy-ping-ePAjWOtt/bin/python3.7)
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/zane/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /Users/zane/.local/s...AjWOtt/bin/python3.7 - setuptools pip wheel:
  Looking in links: /usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages, /usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support, /Users/zane/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv_support
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/06/c8ee69628191285ddddffb277bd5abdf769166e7a14b867c2a172f0175b1/setuptools-40.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/d7/90f34cb0d83a6c5631cf71dfe64cc1054598c843a92b400e55675cc2ac37/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5a/9b/6aebe9e2636d35d1a93772fa644c828303e1d5d124e8a88f156f42ac4b87/wheel-0.32.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip, wheel
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/bin/easy_install'

### ```

...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2343, in 
    main()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 712, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 947, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 904, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 796, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/zane/.local/s...AjWOtt/bin/python3.7 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/bin/pipenv", line 11, in 
    load_entry_point('pipenv==2018.10.13', 'console_scripts', 'pipenv')()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 764, in **call**
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1134, in invoke
    Command.invoke(self, ctx)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 203, in cli
    clear=state.clear,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 565, in ensure_project
    pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 500, in ensure_virtualenv
    python=python, site_packages=site_packages, pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 901, in do_create_virtualenv
    click.echo(crayons.blue("{0}".format(c.err)), err=True) File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/delegator.py", line 146, in err
    return self._pexpect_out
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.10.13/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/delegator.py", line 114, in _pexpect_out
    result += self.subprocess.after
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "type") to str

```

The problem seems to be with:

`Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip, wheel
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/bin/easy_install'`

Comment: Maybe it’s just what it says in error - insufficient permissions. Can you try with “sudo”?